# Wrapping a New Environment Around Theorem Environment

Tags: environments

I'm trying to make a new environment which wraps around a theorem environment defined by `newtheorem` in the `amsthm` package. However, passing in a optional argument into the environment and then into the theorem environment is creating an empty set of parenthesis. The following is a very minimal example of what I'm seeing

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{thm2}[1][]{
    % The following line doesn't work???
    %\ifx&#1&{\begin{thm}}\else{\begin{thm}}\fi
    % However, the following does work but has issues
    \begin{thm}[#1]
}
{
    \end{thm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm2}[Optional Argument] 
    This one looks a little better. 
\end{thm2}

\begin{thm2}
    What's up with the empty argument?
\end{thm2}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Looking online, I found that I can test if #1 is empty or not, but
testing this doesn't seem to do much because `\ifx&#1&{\begin{thm}}\else{\begin{thm}}\fi` simply doesn't compile. How should I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you mentioning `amsthm` when your mwe does not load it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\ifstrempty` from the `etoolbox` package:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{thm2}[1][]{%
    % The following line now works?
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\begin{thm}}{\begin{thm}[#1]}%
}
{%
    \end{thm}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm2}[Optional Argument] 
    This one looks a little better. 
\end{thm2}

\begin{thm2}
    This also look good now as there is no empty argument.
\end{thm2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just expand `\else` and `\fi` before issuing `\begin{thm}`:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{thm2}[1][]
  {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % test for emptiness
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\begin{thm}}{\begin{thm}[1]}%
  }
  {\end{thm}}
\makeatother
```

On the other hand, this is easier with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{thm2}{o}
 {\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\begin{thm}}{\begin{thm}[#1]}
 {\end{thm}}
```